# Probability that uniform distributed variable lies within interval

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If a,b is uniform in [0,1] what is the probability that a/b is in [1,3]

My friend was asked this question in an interview recently but I'm unsure of how to approach it.

I understand that a,b uniform in [0,1] implies the 2 equations 0 <= x <= 1 and 0 <= y <= 1

But I'm unsure how to proceed now.

Comment: Without independence there is no answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer this question, I'll assume $A, B$ are independent and distributed according to $\text{Unif}(0,1)$.

\begin{eqnarray*} && \Pr\left(1 \leq \dfrac{A}{B} \leq 3\right) \\ &=& \Pr\left(\frac{A}{3} \leq B \leq A\right)\\ & = & \int_0^1\int_{a/3}^{a}1dbda \\ & = & \int_0^1\frac{2a}{3}da \\ & = & \frac{1}{3}\end{eqnarray*}

Geometrically, it is the area of the coloured region in the graph below:
[image]